# AJAX post with unknown number of variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form on my website. The questions are stored in the database and some variables determine which questions you see. Thus, the number of questions is unknown. The code for the questions is like this:

**HTML**

```
<ol class="questions">
    <?php
    $number = 1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<li>';
                echo '<span><label for="q'.$number.'">'.$row['question'].'</label></span>';
                echo '<input id="q'.$number.'" name="q'.$number.'" type="text" value="'.$row['description'].'" onclick="this.value="";this.onclick="test";this.style.color="#000000"; setAttribute("type", "text");" onfocus="if (this.value == "'.$row['description'].'") {this.value = ""; setAttribute("type", "text");}"   onblur="if (this.value == "") {this.value = "'.$row['description'].'";setAttribute("type", "text");}"/>';
            echo '</li>';
            $number++;
    };?>
</ol>
```

Now, on submitting the form I want to post the answers to these questions with AJAX. How can I do this with an unknown number of questions?

Comment: where is the ajax code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous author said use `serialize()` function. He didn't mention something I will clarify it now.

JavaScript code:

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "someurl.php",
        method: "post",
        data: $("#myform").serialize()
    });
});
```

And HTML code have to be so:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type='text' name='field1' />
    <input type='text' name='field2' />
    <input type='text' name='etc' />
</form>
<a href='#' id="button">Send ajax</a>
```

Now, when you click `Send ajax` button, form will be serialized (it means to create string, which will containt valid url query, so it can be sent with request). Read about this here: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Hope, this will help.

Ask me if something is unclear.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, second question is; How do I catch it in the PHP?

Comment: @user2755352 did you created new question or what? Or you asking me now?

Comment: I was asking you now if you know the answer to the second problem too ;p

Comment: Better to create new question :) I will answer, sure.

Comment: But there are nothing hard in it. Ajax request is simple request (but yes, you can detect it in php and make some tricks, but... same). So you have to handle ajax request as simple reqest.

Comment: I created a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your form by ajax like that.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    $.post('post.php',$(this).serialize(), function(data) {
         alert(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```